# Linux terminal - frozen update of input but can execute commands?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, console

How do I restart a shell session from within SSH when it looks something like this:

```
anton@ubuntu:~$ c: command not found
                                    anton@ubuntu:~$ lib
                                                       anton@ubuntu:~$ this is working, but its messed up
                         anton@ubuntu:~$
```

I can execute commands, but as I input them nothing shows on the console.  But as soon as I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the command executes and the output comes (without line-endings, as shown above).

```
exec bash
bash --login
clear
```

Nothing really works, restarting the SSH session however works.
The temporary solution is to start a screen session and every time the interface freezes you simply do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>-><kbd>c</kbd> to start a new session and close the old one.

Comment: Try `stty sane`

Comment: Worked some what, after doing it if you press the mouse something like: A2#A2 or N1#N1 comes up :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `reset` might help. See `man reset` for details, but simple `reset` should be just fine.